# How quickly does a MFR Auto-Spawner spawn mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

The MFR [Auto-Spawner](http://ftbwiki.org/Auto-Spawner) can be used to spawn mobs, much like a vanilla mob spawner. The mod [Soul Shards](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Shards) does this as well. I've been told that a tier 5 soul shard spawns mobs faster than the Auto-Spawner, but I want to know how much faster. How fast does an Auto-Spawner spawn things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MFR spawners act much like vanilla spawners so you could take a look at the [algorithm](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner#Detailed_spawning_algorithm). They also require power and mob essence to function. The Tier 5 Soul Shard spawner requires nothing to run, and spawns more mobs faster.

Comment: Hey Andalur, this has gotten a lot of not-an-answer flags.  Could you take another pass at this and see if you can do a better job of answering the question as asked?

Comment: @agent86 Thank you for informing me, I will try.

Comment: This is almost the most perfect answer for this question. I'm an avid user of MFR. The only thing to note, MFR spawners don't require player presence to spawn (however this can be changed via the config file I believe) Other than that, it's pretty much just like Vanilla.